Validation rule blocking creation of amendments
I have created this validation rule where a check box should not be editable on amendment quotes whether you add a new product or edit an existing one.
But this is blocking me from creating amendment quotes or adding new products to it.
OR( 
    AND(
        ISCHANGED(Checkbox__c),
        ISPICKVAL(QuoteType__c, "Amendment"),
        ISPICKVAL(Quote_Source__c, "Internal")
    ), 
    AND( 
        ISNEW(),
        Checkbox__c = True,
        ISPICKVAL(QuoteType__c, "Amendment"),
        ISPICKVAL(Quote_Source__c, "Internal") 
    )
)


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

The ISNEW() condition in the second part of your OR statement will always evaluate to true when creating a new record, and if Checkbox__c is set to True during creation, it will trigger the validation rule.
So it will always equate to True for new records, therefore trigger the validation error and message.
Something like this might work:
AND(
    NOT(ISNEW()),
    ISCHANGED(Checkbox__c),
    ISPICKVAL(QuoteType__c, "Amendment"),
    ISPICKVAL(Quote_Source__c, "Internal")
)

